# Python shell 3.7 restarting program without displaying output or errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

Note that I am an absolute newbie with very little coding experience. I am teaching myself from the ground up and trying my best to google every question I have and comb through my code before asking. I'd like to continue learning as quickly as possible but I'm getting stuck on very simple things.
I'm working on creating classes in Python 3 for the first time and upon trying to run, my program restarts with no error message or output.
My operating system is Windows 10. I've seen answers to questions similar to mine that say it could be an OS problem but I doubt that because this is a very new computer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFW3B.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmB1B.png

Comment: Be a bit more friendly, please copy your code and error to the question but not using a picture. More ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My apologies! I'm still trying to figure the site out and did not mean to come off as rude for not including the code and error in the question. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to use the code boxes, when I enter my code after indenting it ends the code box prematurely. Thank you for the advice, I'll spend more time trying to figure it out.

Comment: @KRB Please see [Stack-overflow's tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: please do not include any screenshots and especially links to screenshots in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS you're doing:

```
if __name__ == "__Main__"
    ...
```

Should be small "m", like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__"
    ...
```

Comment: Bless you! I've been stuck for a really long time trying to figure that out. You've just made a rookie's day.

Comment: @KRB Happy that i helped, , If m answer works please accept it :)